# Javascript ES6 TemplateString a TemplateString

Tags: javascript, render, mustache, template-strings

I am using mustache to build out a single string, replacing several variables within it. I would love to use a TemplateString instead, but I need to resolve my string at runtime, and not at code-compile time since I am reading the template string from an external source.

To be clear:

```
// mustachy example
// template is "foo{{who}}" and myData.whmustao = "manchu"
let myResult = mustache.render(getMyTemplate(),myData);
console.log(myResult);   // "foomanchu"
```

This is pretty lightweight, and I would love to use a TemplateString, but as the example below aludes to - I can't imagine a way to externally provide the string in the first place...

```
// ES6xy example
let myResult = `foo${myData.who}`;   // can't get this at runtime
console.log(myResult);    // "foomanchu"
```

But, I can't imagine a straight-forward, clean, non-sneaky way of achieving this. Can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your replies and creative solutions. However, I thought that there was no solution because TemplateStrings are an in-code feature, whereas other template solutions (like mustache) are a data-driven feature.

Put in other words, ES6's Template Strings is a language feature which limits its functionality to static in-code strings. Any other imagined flexibilities must rely on dynamic execution of a code you inject into your application, which is every hacker's dream.

So the answer to my original thought, as to whether Mustache is overkill for a simple string that is not hard-coded in your source - is NO. Mustache is the acceptable solution for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're loading data on the client and want to generate a string based on the data returned. You could have a function available that returns the generated string for you

```
function generateString(val1, val2) {
  return `foo${val1} bar${val2};
}
```

can you call that function on the client as a result of an api call that gets val1 and val2?

this strategy would also work on the server if you delay your response until you have all the data you need

Comment: But the format of the template string itself is not known in the code, it is provided by an external environment. It is a configuration driven template and cannot exist in the code within `quotes`.

Comment: what format is the template string in? if it's a mustache template then you're basically trying to re-write the Mustache.render function, at which point, you might as well not use Mustache

Answer (score 0):

put the template-string into a function, and pass `myData`

```
let renderMyTemplate = data => `foo${data.who}`;
//or
let renderMyTemplate = ({who}) => `foo${who}`;


let myResult = renderMyTemplate(myData);
console.log(myResult);
```

Comment: But the format of the template string itself is not known in the code, it is provided by an external environment. It is a configuration driven template and cannot exist in the code within `quotes`.

Comment: @InquisitorShm, then your backend has to return Javascript and not plain text/data; template strings are code and not data! You could take a look at JSONP, and use something like `jsonpCallbackName({ myTemplate: function(data){ return \`foo${data.who}\`}, myTemplate2: ... })` or just `jsonpCallbackName(data => \`foo${data.who}\`)` for a single template